# How to enable two button navigation on Android 9?

Tags: 9.0-pie, navigation-bar

OK! This might sound silly, but it's a big problem for me.
I have an IBall ITab Moviez Pro tablet running Android 9. Since it's Android 9, it should have an option to enable two button navigation. But this model doesn't. When I go to **System > Gestures**, there's no option for two button navigation. I did a quick search and found this adb command to enable it:

`adb shell cmd overlay enable com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.twobutton`

This doesn't seem to work at all. When I run this command :

`adb shell cmd overlay list`

to get the list of available overlays, it shows the following:

```
C:\Users\Basudev\Desktop> adb shell cmd overlay list
android
[ ] com.android.internal.display.cutout.emulation.corner
[ ] com.android.internal.display.cutout.emulation.double
[ ] com.android.internal.display.cutout.emulation.tall

com.android.systemui
[x] com.android.systemui.theme.dark
```

From the above output, it seems like `com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.twobutton` is missing from this tablet. Is there any workaround for this?

Tablet specification:

1. Model   : IBall ITab Moviez Pro (IBall IT-KSA0012)
2. Chipset : Unisoc SpreadTrum SC9863A
3. Released with android 9. Currently running the same OS
4. Bootloader is unlocked
5. Device is unrooted
6. No custom recovery installed

Edit: It does show a `Navigation bar` option in setting:
[image]

If I get inside it, it just shows the options to tweak the regular there button navigation bar:
[image]

Here a screenshot of **System > Gestures** page:
[image]

Comment: According to Google you have to enable **System** -> **Gestures** -> **Swipe up on Home button** to get the two button navigation. https://support.google.com/android/answer/9079644?hl=en#zippy=%2Cchoose-how-to-get-around-android

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see in the above screenshot, this option is unavailable. **System > Gestures** has only two options ie **Jump to camera** and **Prevent ringing**. Is there a way to bring back this option somehow?

Comment: They might have removed the customization for system navigation completely...

Comment: @Andrew T. You're right. They have removed it. Is there any way I can add it by myself?